# delete comment on tsv data, and add space in between sentences

Tags: python, pandas

I have 500 tsv data files in a folder, I need to re edit the data.
the original data look like this : [image: Original data]

I removed the comments and the first 2 columns and store them as txt file by using the following code:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

path = "All_TSV_Files"
files = [file for file in os.listdir(path) if file.endswith(".tsv")]

c=0
for file in files:
    df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(path, file), 
                     comment='#', 
                     header=None, 
                     sep='\t',engine='python',error_bad_lines=False)
    
    df.drop(df.columns[[0, 1]], axis=1, inplace=True)
    if len(df.columns)>=3:
        df.to_csv(os.path.join(path, f'admin{c}.txt'),index=False,header=False)
    
    c+=1
```

the result data looks like :
[image: After edit]

But It missing the space in-between each sentence, the result I need is look like :
[image: expected result]

Comment: Try adding this option to your `read_csv`: `skip_blank_lines=False`

Comment: Or modify the `if` statement

Comment: I tried skip_blank_lines, but since I used error_bad_lines=False it skipped all files. @AlexandreLéonard

Comment: sorry, can you give me some example of how the if statement should be ? @steveo314

Comment: I wonder if it has to do with using a tsv... might view all whitespace as just separations. Maybe you could add a row to ```df``` after ```df.drop(df.columns[[0, 1]], axis=1, inplace=True)``` with values of " " in each column. Or you might just need to select a single, non-whitespace character to act as a separator, e.g, "|".

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying your `if` to something like

```
if len(df.columns)>=3 or df[df.columns[0]] == "":
```